Two proofs on intervals of convergence.
So I am working on power series right now for my Real Analysis class, and I need some help on a couple of proofs.

Suppose $(a_n)$ is bounded and that $\sum{a_n}$ diverges. Show that the radius of convergence $R$ of $\sum{{a_n}{x^n}}$ is 1.

So first, if $\sum{a_n}$ diverges, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|} \geq 1$ by the Ratio Test, meaning $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|} \leq 1$. So by the Ratio Criterion, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|} = R \leq 1$. I'm not sure where to go from here. I know that $(a_n)$ bounded means $|a_n| \leq M$ for some $M > 0$, but I don't know how to use this.

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be the interval of convergence of $\sum{{a_n}{x^n}}$. Prove that the interval of convergence of $\sum{{(-1)^n}{a_n}{x^n}}$ is $-A=\{-a : a \in A\}$.
So here, there are 6 possibilities for $A$. If $A = \mathbb{R}$,$[-R,R]$,$(-R,R)$, or $\{0\}$, then $-A=A$. That leaves $A=[-R,R)$ or $A=(-R,R]$. First let $A=[-R,R)$, meaning $\sum{{a_n}{R^n}}$ diverges and $\sum{{a_n}{(-R)^n}}$ converges. Then $\sum{{(-1)^n}{a_n}{R^n}}$ = $\sum{{a_n}{(-R)^n}}$ converges and $\sum{{(-1)^n}{a_n}{(-R)^n}}$ = $\sum{{a_n}{R^n}}$ diverges. Is this correct?


If $\displaystyle\sum a_n$ diverges, the limit of $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$ may not exist, so we cannot use that (although if it exists, it is indeed bigger than $1$ in modulus).
Alternatively, just notice that plugging in $x=1$ into $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ we get $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$, which diverges by hypothesis. Thus, the radius of convergence is at most $1$.
To show that it is equal to $1$, take $x$ such that $|x|=r<1$. As $a_n$ is bounded, there exists some $M>0$ such that $|a_n|<M$ for all $n\geq 1$, so $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_n||x^n|\leq\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} Mr^n<\infty,$$
as the last series is geometric with ratio less than $1$. As the series converges for every $x$ with $|x|<1$, the radius of convergence is exactly $1$.
As for part $2$, your reasoning is right: the root test gives the same result for the original and the alternating series: this means that they share the same interval of convergence. But this interval is always symmetric respect to $0$, so $A=-A$ and we are finished.
Alternatively, you could carry out a straightforward computation: suppose that $a$ is in the interval of convergence and plug in $-a$ into the alternating series, and then do the opposite.
